# How to get fork aligned with upstream/master after commit

Tags: git, github

I made a minor edit on a fork, which I then wanted to add upstream. I saw that my fork had fallen behind by 8 commits and I would like to get it up to date **without a Merge branch 'master' message**.

I added an upstream remote:

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/docker/leeroy
origin  git@github.com:mjbrender/leeroy.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:mjbrender/leeroy.git (push)
upstream    https://github.com/docker/leeroy (fetch)
upstream    https://github.com/docker/leeroy (push)
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   github.go
no changes added to commit
```

I *thought* the correct workflow would be `fetch` the `upstream/master` branch, `pull` it and then I would be in sync. When I did that, I seemed to have merged instead:

```
git fetch upstream master
remote: Counting objects: 19, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 19 (delta 9), reused 18 (delta 8), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (19/19), done.
From https://github.com/docker/leeroy
 * branch                      master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]                master     -> upstream/master
$ git pull upstream master
From https://github.com/docker/leeroy
 * branch                      master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Removing Dockerfile.build
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 Dockerfile                  | 36 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------
 Dockerfile.build            | 21 ---------------------
 MAINTAINERS                 | 33 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 README.md                   | 10 ++++++----
 github/pull_request.go      | 14 --------------
 github/pull_request_test.go | 28 ----------------------------
 handlers.go                 | 17 +++--------------
 7 files changed, 70 insertions(+), 89 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 Dockerfile.build
 create mode 100644 MAINTAINERS
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 9 commits.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I believe I need to edit my default pull behavior to rebase instead of merge. My question for here is this: how do I get back to a state that is 1 commit ahead of `upstream/master` so I can open the pull request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you actually want to pop off the commits that you made locally, update to be in sync with `upstream/master` and then push your commits back on top without any merge commits.  You can do all that with a simple command:

```
git pull --rebase . upstream/master
```

You can also accomplish this another way.  First update your remotes, then rebase:

```
git remote update
git rebase upstream/master
```

Comment: Thank you! How does rebase work in this instance? I don't get it.

Comment: a `git rebase` is an action that pops off your local commits, sync's with a specified target ref, and then pushes your local commits back onto the head.

Answer (score -2):

It i important to understand that Git branches are merely pointers to commits. What you want to do is simple revert your current branch's pointer to the previous position of your working directory. There is a Git shortcut for that `HEAD@{1}`.

The shortcut looks at the reflog (which is a log of where a particular ref was on your local machine.), so it has nothing to do with what you will see in `git log`.

This will actually do the move:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: This is good information, but not at all what the OP is asking for.

Comment: OP will lose work or at best go into a temporary blind panic if they follow this advice.